# Helpful ASP / VB Libraries

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm working with ASP Classic professionally and I will have to do a bigger project that will be important for school (we have a system where you have two days school and 3 days work). Now I'm a little worried because I do not feel really productive with VB compared to the languages I use personally.

A friend of mine told me about a great php library that fixes a lot of problem and just makes his life a lot simpler. Now I'm look for something like that for VB. For example, some more abstractions for arrays (sort ...) or even other data structures like hashmaps.

I could write a lot of stuff like that myself but I don't have time.

So the general question: Can you recommend useful libraries for somebody that uses ASP Classic/VB for database heavy websites?

Comment: Why is VB6/ASP Classic the only language you can use? VS Express with VB.Net and the .Net framework would put you light years ahead of VB6 for DB dependent web apps.

Comment: It not my choise what to use.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://ajaxed.org/ i'm using it and i think it's quite cool.

it is similar to php library xajax plus it has lots of additional methods for developing in classic asp vbscript

AND it is very well documented!